# Substitution with backreferencing in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I have a frequent pattern on my text, say

```
(Eq. \ref{XXXX})
```

where `XXXX` is some word, and I'd like to change all this simply to

```
\refp{XXXX}
```

I can't make it work through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, even with Regex. The syntax

```
\(Eq. \\ref{.*}\)
```

works for finding the occurences (if with some bugs...) but the traditional backreferencing

```
\\refp{\1}
```

won't work for the replacement.

I tried to create a custom command with the atom-shell-commands package, the idea would be to use sed on the current selection. But the package won't accept octal escape sequences.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement tokens use a `$` sigil, not `\`. So you want `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...

The replacement in this case should be:

```
\\refp{$1}
```

As is common with regex matching, these tokens match the contents of paren groups, from left to right. So you need to add matching parens also. Your match string would be:

```
\(Eq. \\ref{(.*)}\)
```

Note there are parens around the `.*` match, so whatever is inside those parens is stored in `$1`. If there were a second and third set of parens, those would become `$2` and `$3`.

Comment: Thank you, that was my inexperience speaking out loud. This worked inside Atom, but there are some weird bugs. In some (apparently random) cases the find command will highlight everything following the match until it finds the next right parenthesis, I can't figure why.

Also, the atom-shell-commands package at least accepted the bakcreferencing, but the command I created with sed doesn't actually work. This is a different matter though, perhaps I should create a new question.

Comment: @rodrigomp That smells like a regex issue perhaps. But yes might be best asked separately.